# Node:events:505 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js

when i npm run serve on my vue file, continuously seen this error
i already delete node.js and reinstall and nvm, npm also that
but didn't work, only this project seen like this error

RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code 17235
at Receiver.controlMessage (/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/snut/vue/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:561:18)
at Receiver.getData (/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/snut/vue/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:429:42)
at Receiver.startLoop (/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/snut/vue/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:148:22)
at Receiver._write (/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/snut/vue/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:83:10)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:390:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:331:10)
at Receiver.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:335:10)
at Socket.socketOnData (/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/snut/vue/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1231:35)
at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
at Receiver.receiverOnError (/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/snut/vue/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1117:13)
at Receiver.emit (node:events:527:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'WS_ERR_INVALID_CLOSE_CODE',
[Symbol(status-code)]: 1002
}

Answer (score 0):

just clear the cache with this:

```js
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```